# Authenticate user with Smart Card and LDAP in Tomcat 7

Tags: java, tomcat, authentication

I have a web application running on Tomcat 7 and it is configured with a custom JNDIRealm and my login-config auth-method in my web.xml is set to "FORM".

I am trying to find a way to add the ability to authenticate users through the same LDAP with a smart card, if presented.

I have changed my server.xml to have `clientAuth=want`, but want to know if there is a way to authenticate the user when a certificate is presented via the LDAP and then re-direct them past the login form. Is this possible?

**EDIT:** Michael-O below was marked as the right answer because I was able to achieve this by creating a custom class that extends FormAuthenticator and then registering that in Tomcat's authenticator.properties. This allowed me to check for a x509cert from the client in the request. If the cert is present and valid, authenticate and forward the user to the secured resources page. If not present or invalid, forward the user to the form login.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You obviously do not now what you want or what technologies you are actually using. Smartcard authentication is mutual SSL authentication. So you first need to configure Tomcat to accept SSL-based authentication. Your realm will receive the X509 certs and will try find your DN in your data store. The store can be anything, database, files, directory, etc.

Comment: Tomcat already accepts SSL based authentication for the app. A key and trust store is set on the server. It works currently with form login with an LDAP group set. I can enter the username and password of a user and log in. I am trying to have Tomcat redirect to secure resources when an accepted client cert is presented from a card.

Comment: This is weird. How is form auth connected to cert auth? Cert auth is a layer below than HTTP. I confused about your form stuff.

Comment: The app was already using form auth with SSL and clientAuth=false. I am seeing if it is possible when I set clientAuth=want, and a cert from a card is present, to redirect to the user secure resources.

Comment: In theory, yes. But I think you need to roll your own authenticator. You will need a hybrid authenticator consisting of SSL followed by form redirect. The base authenticators provded by Tomcat do not provide that.

Comment: Thanks. I am trying to do that by overriding some methods in my custom JNDIRealm class. Do you know what the primary method is for checking roles? I thought it was JNDIRealm.getRoles, but it doesn't seem to go in there.

Comment: It is not just the realm. First, it is the authenticator which has to offer both methods. Then the realm kicks in with the `authenticate`` method. The role checking is performed by the `RealmBase`.