# Disable client authentication for specified path

Tags: tomcat, ssl, authentication

I have a java web application running in tomcat, which uses client authentication. In my tomcats `server.xml` config file I have configured the `clientAuth` attribute in my 8443 connector to `true`. 
This works as it should, but now I have the need of a couple of 'public' pages in this application that should not ask for client authentication. So I was wondering if it is possible with tomcat to 'disable' client authentication for specific configured paths or how can I achieve what I need?

EDIT:

Or is it possible to have different Connectors for different Contexts (webapps) ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In theory, Tomcat should enforce auth only on paths you have protected in your `web.xml`. You cannot define excludes.

Comment: I have not defined anything in my web.xml about client authentication. Not sure what you mean or what I should add.

Comment: If I understand correctly, I should put clientAuth (server.xml) to false and add constraints with CLIENT-CERT in my web.xml?

Comment: Yes, have the application enforce then authentication on specific paths only.

Comment: One more question. With this configuration I have to add all users to tomcat-user.xml? Because that is not an option in my use case...

Comment: Not necessarily. You will always need some `Realm` implementation. The `tomcat-users.xml` is only necessary if you want to use the `UserDatabaseRealm` which is not well suited for production.

Comment: I need users to be able to authenticate using a smart card reader and their eID card (X.509). Any idea how I should configure for this?

Comment: I thought you have already done that? SSL authenticator and any realm? See my answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/25982351/696632

Comment: Yes originally it was configured with clientAuth="true" and that worked. Now I'm getting following error: Status 401 - Cannot authenticate with the provided credentials

Comment: Check for the realm. That is your problem.

Comment: Hmm so it can't just make use of the truststore i defined in the Connector where I added trusted CA root certificates?

Comment: You need to check whether the SSL context fails here or the realm. You should enable logging for the SSL authenticator.